# My pet emperor scorpion is not eating

Tags: feeding, exotic-pets, scorpions

I have bought a female emperor scorpion 20 days back. But she has not eaten still now.

I try to maintain the right temperature by placing heating mat under the tank. I try to maintain right humidity by misting the enclosure daily. So I don't think that environment is a problem.

I keep a gut loaded cricket at night but at morning I find that the scorpion has not eaten it.

I am now really worried about her. I don't want her to fall sick? What should I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to worry. Scorpions can live long periods of time without eating anything. And an adult emperor scorpions can stop eating for months at a time.

Also juvenile scorpions stop eating when they are about to molt. When they get really fat, it is usually the time when they will molt. They stop molting when they reach adulthood.

If your scorpion is hungry it will eat. I would also stop try to give a cricket every night to see if the scorpion eats. It would be ideal if you try a gut loaded cricket or meal worm after every 3-4 days. Put the insect in the tank at night. If not eaten take out in morning.